# Why doesn't std::enable_shared_from_this use a mutable std::weak_ptr?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, shared-ptr, mutable, enable-shared-from-this

I understand that most std library implementations choose to implement `std::enable_shared_from_this` by storing a `std::weak_ptr` in the base class. This leads to the following:

```
#include <memory>

class Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> GetSharedBar() const
    {
        // returns shared_ptr<const Foo> instead of std::shared_ptr<Foo>
        return shared_from_this();
        // Error in VC++2019 due to mismatch.
    }
};
```

It seems clear to me that despite needing to update the reference count, `shared_from_this()` is not actually mutating the target object. This seems like an ideal use for mutable, so that `shared_from_this()` can be marked as `const` with respect to the derived object.

Why isn't it implemented with `mutable`?

To elucidate the answer below: it is implemented with the `std::weak_ptr` marked `mutable`, but that only allows the `std::weak_ptr` to be mutated, not for us to hand off a non-`const` to someone else.

Comment: @Eljay, are you using VC++? I updated the sample to include everything necessary to reproduce my observation.

Comment: Surely this behaviour is correct though? In `GetSharedBar()`, `this` is a pointer to a `const` `Foo`. You can't possibly return it as pointer to a non-`const` `Foo` (wrapped in a `shared_ptr<>` or otherwise) without some casting shenanigans.

Comment: Well my understanding is that std::enable_shared_from_this constains a std::weak_ref pointing at this, not const this. If the weak_ref is marked mutable, would we not be able to then instantiate a std::shared_ptr pointing at this using the copy constructor?

Comment: I think it's working as intended, if you take out the shared pointer and just attempt to return `this` as a non-const pointer or reference you'll get the same error

Comment: *Why isn't it implemented with mutable?*  The control block **is** implemented with mutable.  The problem is either the method needs to be non-const, or the return type needs to be `std::shared_ptr<Foo const>`, or you need to `return const_cast<Foo*>(this)->shared_from_this()` which is janky.

Comment: @Eljay In almost every STL container, the elements are "implemented with mutable" by your def? (Although of course the public interface of STL containers apply deep constness on elements.)

Comment: @curiousguy • The shared_ptr's **control block**.  Not the elements.

Comment: @Eljay Again: by your own definition, are the elements of a container "implemented with mutable"?

Comment: @curiousguy • The elements of a container are not implemented with mutable.  That is not my definition.  For a container that holds `const` elements, the `const` elements are immutable (at least logically, C++ provides means to circumvent that, possibly leading to UB) unless members are marked mutable.  For a `shared_ptr`, the **control block** is mutable, so even a `const shared_ptr` can make more shared pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[These both fail to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/8sjen3):

```
class Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> GetSharedBar() const
    {
        // error: could not convert from 'shared_ptr<const Foo>' to 'shared_ptr<Foo>'
        return shared_from_this();
    }
};

class Bla
{
public:
    Bla* getThis() const
    {
        // error: invalid conversion from 'const Bla*' to 'Bla*'
        return this;
    }
};
```

But they both work if you remove `const` from the functions. The issue is that in a `const` member function, the `this` pointer is a `const` pointer.

As another example, take this:

```
class kluf
{
    const std::string* k;
    std::string* getK() 
    {
        // error: invalid conversion from 'const string*' to 'std::string*'
        return k;
    }
};
```

Clearly you are not allowed to hand a `const` member off to somebody else in a non-`const` state. This also goes for the `this` pointer, and in a `const` function `this` is `const`.

Comment: Thanks, your second to last sentence by itself did the trick for me thinking about this! Problem isn't one of the `std::weak_ptr` being mutated, but rather handing off a non-const as a return value to someone else.